# How to style and position a legend in a plot with multiple geom_point layers?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

This is my attempt:

```r
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = standard_expression_TS.kmeans.df, aes(A, B, color = "DF1")) +
  geom_point( data = experimental_expression_TS.kmeans.df, aes(A, B, color = "DF2"), shape = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(standard_expression_TS.kmeans$centers), aes(A, B, color='DF3'), shape=4, size=8) + 
  labs(title="Expression Scatterplot") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("DF1"="black", "DF2"="blue", "DF3"="red"), name="Genes")
```

And this is how my plot looks:[image]

I am trying to add a legend that has each of the 3 point types (black dot, blue circle, red x) followed by a string ("DF1", "DF2", "DF3"). If possible, I would love to have it ON the plot, flush with the bottom left corner.

**Note:** I am looking for a way of doing this that avoids melting all the data together.

EDIT: When I change the names of "DF1-3", it stops working.

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_jitter(data = mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = "Standard")) +
  geom_jitter(data = mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = "Experimental"), shape = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_jitter(data = mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color='Center'), shape=4, size=8) + 
  labs(title="Expression Scatterplot") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = c(0, 0),
        legend.justification = c("left", "bottom")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("Standard"="black", "Experimental"="blue", "Center"="red"), name="Genes") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16, 1, 4), size = c(1.5, 1.5, 8))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mtcars` as example dataset and `geom_jitter` instead of `geom_point` this could be achieved like so:

1. The legend can be styled via `guide_legend` which allows you to override the default aes to specifiy the `shape` and `size` of each legend key
2. The positioning of the legend could be achieved via theme options `legend.position` and `legend.justification`. `legend.justification` sets the x- and y-axis anchor for the positioning of the legend, while `legend.position` (between 0 and 1) sets the position relative to these anchor.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_jitter(data = mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = "DF1")) +
  geom_jitter(data = mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = "DF2"), shape = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_jitter(data = mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color='DF3'), shape=4, size=8) + 
  labs(title="Expression Scatterplot") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = c(0, 0),
        legend.justification = c("left", "bottom")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("DF1"="black", "DF2"="blue", "DF3"="red"), name="Genes") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16, 1, 4), size = c(1.5, 1.5, 8))))
```

[image]

The easiest way to change the labels in the legend is to set them via `labels` in `scale_color_manual`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_jitter(data = mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = "DF1")) +
  geom_jitter(data = mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = "DF2"), shape = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_jitter(data = mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color='DF3'), shape=4, size=8) + 
  labs(title="Expression Scatterplot") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = c(0, 0),
        legend.justification = c("left", "bottom")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(DF1 = "black", DF2 = "blue", DF3 = "red"), 
                      labels = c(DF1 = "Standard", DF2 = "Experimental", DF3 = "Center"),
                      name = "Genes") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16, 1, 4), size = c(1.5, 1.5, 8))))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Looks like guide_legend(override.aes) was the key. Can I also use guide_legend to center the legend title (in this case, "Genes")?

Comment: @Nova. Yep. You can center the position by adding `title.hjust = .5` as argument to `guide_legend`.

Comment: It seems to stop working when I change the names from "DF1-3" to something else. Check my edit. I think it's because it does it in alphabetical order.

Comment: Hi @Nova. You are right. The legend items are ordered alphabetically. Unfortunately the standard appraoch to solve this via a named vector does not work with guide_legend. Instead I would recommend to stick with "DF1"-"DF3" to get the right order and set the labels via the `labels` argument in `scale_color_manual`. See my edit.